# the auxiliary equation for the given differential equation has complex roots. $z''-6z'+10z=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble solving this problem. Would anyone be able to help me?
the auxiliary equation for the given differential equation has complex roots. $z''-6z'+10z=0$

Comment: Have you not been shown what to do with the function $z=e^{\alpha x}$ when $\alpha$ is complex?

Answer (score 3):

If the roots are $\alpha\pm i\beta$ with $\beta\ne0$, then the solution is
$$z=e^{\alpha t}(A\cos\beta t+B\sin\beta t)\ .$$
Alternatively, you can write the solution in complex form
$$z=Ce^{\alpha+i\beta}+De^{\alpha-i\beta}\ ,$$
which is essentially just what you would have written if the roots had been real.

To see that the two forms of the solution are equivalent, write the second as
$$\eqalign{z
  &=Ce^{\alpha t}(\cos\beta t+i\sin\beta t)+De^{\alpha t}(\cos\beta t-i\sin\beta t)\cr
  &=e^{\alpha t}\bigl((C+D)\cos\beta t+(C-D)i\sin\beta t\bigr)\ .\cr}$$
If you want a real solution, you can choose complex constants $C$ and $D$ such that $D=\overline C$; then the coefficients $C+D$ and $(C-D)i$ will both be real.  Thus you have the first form of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: if the complex roots of the characteristic equation of a 2nd order homogenous ODE are $r_{1,2} = a \pm b \mathrm{i}$, then $\{e^{ax}\cos{bx},e^{ax}\sin{bx}\}$ is a set of fundamental solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for complex solutions in form $y(x)=e^{zx}$, where $z$ is complex, so:

$$y''-6y'+10y=z^2e^{zx}-6ze^{zx}+10e^{zx}=(z^2-6z+10)e^{zx}=0$$

Because $e^{zx} \neq 0$, it must be $z^2-6z+10=0$. Next:

$$z^2-6z+10=(z-3)^2+1=0$$

so you have complex solutions $z_1=3+i$ and $z_2=3-i$, thus you have two compex solutions $y_1=e^{z_1 x}=e^{3x}(\cos x+ i \sin x)$ and $y_2=e^{z_2 x}=e^{3x}(\cos (-x)+i \sin(-x))=e^{3x}(\cos x-i \sin x)$. Bou you know that linear combinations of solutions is also solution. So $y_1+y_2$ and $i(y_1-y_2)$ also are solutions and they're real.

Comment: It's a little bit confusing your choice of $y$ and the complex parameter $z$ since OP's dependent variable is actually $z$.